# Is it OK to use a signal as component Input in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-signals

In the following mock-up I use a signal as an input to a component. It works.  But I am wondering if this is the proper use of a signal.  Seems....weird.

The follwing is a service that maintains a list of My Friends:

```js
import {
  Injectable,
  signal
} from '@angular/core';

export interface MyFriend {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyFriendsService {
  myFriends = signal < MyFriend[] > ([{
      name: 'Bob',
      age: 34,
    },
    {
      name: 'Julie',
      age: 30,
    },
    {
      name: 'Martin',
      age: 25,
    },
  ]);
}
```

The folowing is a Friend Detail Component that shows the detail of a particular friend:

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  computed,
  signal
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MyFriend,
  MyFriendsService
} from './my-friends.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-friend-detail',
  templateUrl: './friend-detail-component.html',
})
export class FriendDetailComponent {
  @Input() name = signal('Bob');
  friendDetail = computed < MyFriend > (() => {
    const friend = this.myFriendsService
      .myFriends()
      .filter((friend) => friend.name === this.name());
    if (friend.length > 0) {
      return friend[0];
    }
    return {
      name: '',
      age: 0,
    };
  });
  constructor(private myFriendsService: MyFriendsService) {}
```

The following component simply uses the FriendDetailComponent:

```js
import {
  Component,
  signal
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  template: `<app-friend-detail [name]="selectedName"></app-friend-detail>`,
})
export class SomeComponent {
  selectedName = signal < string > ('Julie');
}
```

As I said, this WORKS.  But...is this a proper way to be using a signal in angular?

FYI, I realize that the FriendDetailComponent should be more "dumb" and just accept the input of the FriendDetail info (it need not use signals)...but I did this mock-up as a way to explain a pattern I fell into within the context of a more complex situation.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing signals, just like you shouldn't pass Observables. If the child component is smart, give it access to the service. If it's dumb, then you should be passing it the already-consumed signal. As always, there's a lot of "it depends", but if signals are to be seen the same way as Observables, this will be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @WillAlexander, you are expressing what my hunch is telling me.  This is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 6):

###### Edit: model inputs available since [Angular 17.2](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v17-2-is-now-available-596cbe96242d)

---

Phase 2 (or maybe Phase 3) of Signals will introduce `signal: true` components, which will include two-way bindings.

The RFC https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682 describes this under `Model inputs`.

In short (and API is subject to change) you will be able to define a special type of input that can be manipulated as a signal but will be a two way binding back to the parent.

But you won't be passing a signal directly, it will just appear as a signal inside the component.

If you're trying to pass signals to a component today you can do that via a service or just a normal input which is set to the evaluated signal value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's out just now, in V 17.1.0 RC0

Answer (score -1):

[EDIT] since 17.1 you can now use a [signal as input](https://angular.io/guide/signal-inputs#signal-inputs). There is no need for `@Input()` anymore:

```js
firstName = input<string>(); //InputSignal<string|undefined>
```

Previous answer below:

It's not yet ready, you can however convert a regular input into a signal one using this helper:

```js
//signal-property.helper.ts
import { signal, Signal } from '@angular/core';

const cacheMap = Symbol('Cached values');

function getObservableMap<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T
): Map<K, Signal<T[K]>> {
    // upsert the cacheMap
    return ((obj as any)[cacheMap] =
        (obj as any)[cacheMap] ?? new Map<any, any>());
}

function isUsingAccessor<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    variable: K
): boolean {
    // the prototype of the object (and not the own property) is holding information about the object getters at the time of the construction
    const prototypeOfObject = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    const descriptorOfPrototype = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
        prototypeOfObject,
        variable
    );
    return (
        !!descriptorOfPrototype &&
        ('get' in descriptorOfPrototype || 'set' in descriptorOfPrototype)
    );
}

function checkIsNotAccessor<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    variable: K
): void {
    if (isUsingAccessor(obj, variable)) {
        throw new Error('Listening value accessors is not supported');
    }
}

function createSignalProperty<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    variable: K
): Signal<T[K]> {
    const defaultDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor =
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, variable) ??
        defaultPropertyDescriptor();
    const aSignal = signal<T[K]>(undefined as any);

    checkIsNotAccessor(obj, variable);

    const { enumerable, configurable } = defaultDescriptor;
    const descriptor: PropertyDescriptor = {
        configurable,
        enumerable,
        get: () => defaultDescriptor.value,
        set: (nextValue) => {
            defaultDescriptor.value = nextValue;
            aSignal.set(nextValue);
        },
    };

    const isValueAlreadyDeclared = 'value' in defaultDescriptor;
    if (isValueAlreadyDeclared) {
        aSignal.set(defaultDescriptor.value);
    }

    Object.defineProperty(obj, variable, descriptor);

    return aSignal.asReadonly();
}

function defaultPropertyDescriptor(): PropertyDescriptor {
    return {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
    };
}

export function asSignal<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    property: K
): Signal<T[K]> {
    const map = getObservableMap(obj);

    if (!map.has(property)) {
        map.set(property, createSignalProperty(obj, property));
    }
    // casting is mandatory
    return map.get(property)! as Signal<T[K]>;
}
```

usage is as follows:

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { asSignal } from '../../../shared/helpers/signal/signal-property.helper';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sub-test',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    template: '{{valueSignal()}}', // print the signal
    styleUrls: ['./sub-test.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SubTestComponent {
    @Input()
    value!: string;
    valueSignal = asSignal(this, 'value'); // here is a signal of value
}
```